# Do plants feel pain upon being cut?

Tags: plants, hell

Do Plants feel pain when we cut them or kill them ? Are people punished for killing for hurting or teasing plants meaninglessly ?

Comment: pain is not binary 0 or 1. there are varying levels of pain depending upon amount of Vyana vayu in their bodies. in scientific parlance this is known as nervous system. plants feel pain when cut but the pain is minimal. it would be the same amount of pain we feel if an ant bites us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trees feel pain according to Hindu scripture and science.

> 49. These (plants) which are surrounded by multiform Darkness, the result of their acts (in former existences), possess internal
>     consciousness and experience pleasure and **pain**.

**Manu Smriti I.49**

Science is also now beginning to accept the idea that trees feel pain.

> One of the first things we talked about was how plants feel pain.
> Fellow foresters roll their eyes when I talk about spruce feeling pain when they are attacked by bark
> beetles. '**Of course a plant, trees can feel pain**," the professor
> [Baluska] answered when asked about it.

**The Heartbeat of trees, chapter 15. The disappearing boundary between animals and plants by Peter Wohlleben**

**Are people punished for hurting trees?**

I don't know but it is better not to hurt any sentient being unnecessarily.

Comment: pain felt by trees and pain felt by animals and pain felt by humans are all different. the word pain has different meanings to different species.

Comment: The common link between pain felt by trees, animals and humans is that no one likes pain.

Comment: false. i feel pain when lifting weights, but i like that pain because it gives me a greater pleasure later. i feel pain when a surgeon cuts me, but i like that pain because it gives me a greater pleasure later. also, the pain i feel when my hair is pulled and cut by barber, is different from the pain i feel when the barber plucks my hair out with tweezers. pain is not a single word or emotion. it is a range. saying plants and animals feel pain is like saying both humans and plants communicate. sure, but there is a world of difference.

Comment: Undoubtedly there are some weirdos who are masochistic. However, animals and trees do not show any masochism. I was stressing commonality and not difference.

Comment: this has nothing to do with sadism or masochism. i'm stressing the difference in levels of pain that a species can possibly feel. the amount of vyana vayu is miniscule in plants, hence their level of "pain" even when killed is much lower than that of animals, which is much lower than that of humans.